# How to make custom file format in Java

Tags: java, android, file-security

I am making a application in Android.
I have lot of file on Server like abc.doc, abc.xls, abc.mp3 etc. 
I want to download all these file in a single file like .zip, .rar then store it on SDCARD.
Than only my application able to read these file no other application able to read it for security issue.

Answer (score 2):

The only secure way would be to use encryption for securing the file. You could for example use simple symmetric encryption using AES or something similar. The `java.security` package contains all the required classes for this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/package-summary.html

**EDIT:**

For a custom binary file format you could use `DataInputStream`. It allows to read different data types from an binary input stream. See the docs for details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html

Comment: Thank you chkal for answer but the link show me file security but i want to make custom file format like .doc or .psd and want to make reader for that.

Comment: I also would use encryption for this. Custom format is secure only until someone reverse-engineers it.